# OpenWrt: do manually configured ip assignments survive a reboot?

Tags: ip, dhcp, openwrt, dnsmasq

As far as I know if I want to make an ip address static, I have to put it into `/etc/ethers` file. But does it survive a reboot 100% (stored in persistent storage)?
I don't want to mess with it and check it out, because I might do it wrong and don't know if dnsmasq will load in this case and work or I might end up with ethernet not working.
The question is vital because I have to make sure that if I move my router to some other place with my other devices (to show demo to a customer), I don't want to end up with devices not working due to another ip address assigned. (I know its really bad to hardcode ip address in software, but lets leave it alone).
I have OpenWrt running on the router.

Comment: Best to set static ip in dhcp server, so all configurations are in one place. Also if you are moving around, then you have to avoid IP conflicts, even non-routable reusable addresses could conflict if you attach to someone else's network. Luckily there is ipv6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OpenWrt device with a hardware button or serial port for configuration experiments.  Then if the device becomes inaccessible due to configuration error, you can boot it in failsafe mode and follow documented proceedures to restore a known-good configuration.

- https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe
- https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe#when_you_are_in_failsafe_mode

`/etc/*` is persisted in a writable filesystem using an overlay mount.  (Usually.  Don't ask me what the images for standard x86 machines do).  Failsafe mode avoids mounting the overlay, so it boots using the initial config.